# Java - get "program files" path

Tags: java, windows, path

How can I get the current computer's "Program Files" path with Java?

Comment: What is the use of gaining such an arcane and OS specific directory?  What are you actually trying to achieve by knowing that information?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Simply by calling [`System.getenv(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))

```
System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
```

Notice it will only work in Windows environments, of course :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
System.getenv("%programfiles% (x86)");
```

for the 32-bit folder on 64-bit PC's.

Also, it works on any language in Windows Vista and newer. Calling either of the posted responses will work on any language installation, in fact.

Answer (score 4):

For 32 bit use:

```
    System.out.println(System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)"));
```

For 64 bit use:

```
    System.out.println(System.getenv("ProgramFiles"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the System.getenv() method:

```
public class EnvironmentVariableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getenv("ProgramFiles"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("MadeUpEnvVar"));
    }
}
```

If the variable doesn't exist, it will simply return null.